# Knowage autogenerated query understanding

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, fiware-knowage

I'm using knowage software for data analysis, I'm facing performance issues, now I'm watching 'dataset audit' log to see what queries does the system perform. I found this one that, to me, is a nonsense:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM 

(select TOP(100) PERCENT "ATC_1" AS "ATC_1" 
from 

    (SELECT [ID_AFo]
          ,[ATC]
          ,[ATC_1]
          ,[ATC_3]
          ,[ATC_4]
          ,[ATC_5]

      FROM [AFO]

        ) T  order by "ATC_1" ASC
) u
```

inner `T` query is the dataset definition query I entered that basically is a `select * from [AFO]` on my table, outer wrap are made by knowage (I never wrote them)

doesn't a `select count (*) from T` have performed the same calculation but avoiding a cexpensive order by?

EDIT:
Backend (data source) is MSSQL, cache server is MYSQL so frequent queries are on mysql

Answer (score 0):

This query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [AFO];
```

The only reason that I can think of for constructing such a query is if the "100" could be set to another value.  I'm not sure if SQL Server's optimizer is good enough to eliminate the `ORDER BY` in the subquery.

Comment: On MSSQL, comparing the estimated query plans select count(*) and the query above I got substantially no difference, so for MSSQL it's the same... I'd like to know on mysql

Comment: In SQL Server the `TOP 100 PERCENT` was used by some "clever" programmers to allow ORDER BY in views. Until the optimizer got smarter and removed it. First they complained about this being a "bug" and later they switched to `TOP 99.99999999999999 PERCENT` or `TOP 1000000000000` instead :-)

Comment: @DDS . . . The query as written doesn't run on MySQL, so the question is moot.

Comment: I don't know exactly on which instance it runs, i tested in on MSSQL and works, so probably it's the first data collection.... Looking at it it's clearer as cache generated tables have names like 'dscache*****'